# For loop keeps getting jupyter stuck

Tags: python, for-loop, random-forest

I am new to data analysis and python, in class, we were making a for loop to check different no trees in the random forest and find out the one with the best accuracy, our teacher gave us the assignment to achieve this by a for loop, but the code I wrote makes the notebook stuck and doesn't give an output, can someone please tell me what is wrong with my code? Like, I finally got the answer but after a very long time, can anyone tell me how to do the same thing more efficiently without making any changes to the range?

```py
accuracy_scores = []
for i in range(50,500,10):
    model_random = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=i,criterion="entropy",max_features=10,min_samples_leaf=50)
    model_random.fit(X_train,Y_train)
    Y_pred=model_random.predict(X_test)
    accuracy=round(accuracy_score(Y_pred, Y_test)*100,2)
    accuracy_scores.append(accuracy)
print(max(accuracy_scores))
y=accuracy_scores.index(max(accuracy_scores))*10+50
print(y)
```

Comment: You could at some print() statements between each line in your for loop to see the progress. Maybe training just one classifier takes a long time on your machine, caused by your CPU power

Comment: `print()` something in the loop to keep track of the loop progress (n = 50, accuracy = x.xx% for example).. It should helps in ur troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for loop is correct. I'm assuming your RandomForestClassifier function is taking some time to calculate.

My suggestion is to add some print/logger statement to see where and what takes the most amount of time.

```
from time import per_counter

for i in range(50, 500, 10):
    start = perf_counter()
    model_random = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=i,criterion="entropy",max_features=10,min_samples_leaf=50)
    calc_time = perf_counter() - start
    print(f"RandomForestClassifier took {calc_time:.2f}")
    Y_pred=model_random.predict(X_test)
    accuracy=round(accuracy_score(Y_pred, Y_test)*100,2)
    accuracy_scores.append(accuracy)

print(max(accuracy_scores))
y=accuracy_scores.index(max(accuracy_scores))*10+50
print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use GridSearchCV() instead of the for loop.

You can apply the example shown [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_grid_search_digits.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-grid-search-digits-py) in your code and see if the performance improves compared to the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

It is not stuck, it is just processing. I have modified your code to show the point

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import numpy as np
import timeit

M = 5000
features = 10000
train_prop = 0.75
M_train = int(M*train_prop)
M_test = M - M_train

X_train = np.random.rand(M_train, features)
X_test = np.random.rand(M_test, features)
Y_train = (np.random.rand(M_train)>0.5).astype(int)
Y_test = (np.random.rand(M_test)>0.5).astype(int)

accuracy_scores = []
for i in range(50,500,10):
    t1 = timeit.default_timer()
    print(f"Estimators {i}")
    model_random = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=i,criterion="entropy",max_features=10,min_samples_leaf=50, n_jobs=None)
    model_random.fit(X_train,Y_train)
    Y_pred=model_random.predict(X_test)
    accuracy=round(accuracy_score(Y_pred, Y_test)*100,2)
    accuracy_scores.append(accuracy)
    delta_t = timeit.default_timer() - t1
    print(f"Processing time [seconds] {delta_t}")
print(max(accuracy_scores))
y=accuracy_scores.index(max(accuracy_scores))*10+50
print(y)
```

The amount of processing time will depend on the number of samples you are processing (M variable). If you increase or decrease that variable you will see how processing time changes accordingly.

Notice that the number of features (features variable) does not impact the processing time much.

As you can notice I have added the optional parameter n_jobs=None, which means you are using only one processor. If you change it to n_jobs=-1, will use all the available processors and the processing time will decrease.